# Polyalphabetic cipher in python, decode method doesn't work

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to implement some basic ciphers in Python. The one I'm stuck on is a polyalphabetic cipher. I've seen other posts on here that use the same term for what appears to be a different cipher, so I'll specify I'm trying to implement what [this textbook](http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/section-private-key-crypt.html) calls a polyalphabetic cipher in chapter 7, section 1. This involves digitizing the message, breaking it up into vectors of equal length, multiplying each one by a set matrix (that is invertible, mod 26), adding a shift vector, and reversing the digitization to get the encoded message out.

Using the example in the textbook, I'm trying to encode "HELP" with matrix [[3, 5], [1, 2]] and shift vector [2, 2], and it is encoding to "RRGR" as the book says it should. However, when I apply my decode method to "RRGR" to "HELO". In case more data is helpful, I'll add that when I encode and then decode the whole alphabet with the same matrix and shift vector I get "ABCDEFGGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWWYZ".

My code is below (apologies for the lack of comments, this code isn't for anything important so I didn't bother):

```
import numpy as np

class Polyalphabetic:
    def __init__(self, alphabet, vec_len, shift, mult):
        self.alphabet = alphabet
        self.vec_len = vec_len
        self.mod = len(alphabet)
        self.shift = np.array(shift)
        self.mult = np.array(mult)
        self.inv = np.linalg.inv(mult) % self.mod

    def digitize(self, string):
        return [alphabet.index(letter) for letter in string]

    def undigitize(self, int_list):
        return ''.join([alphabet[i] for i in int_list])

    def encode(self, message):
        digits = self.digitize(message)

        output_vectors = []
        for i in range(len(digits) // self.vec_len):
            in_vec = digits[self.vec_len * i : self.vec_len * (i + 1)]
            multed_vec = np.matmul(self.mult, in_vec)
            shifted_vec = (multed_vec + self.shift)
        
            out_vec = shifted_vec.astype(int) % self.mod
            output_vectors.append(out_vec)
    
        encoded = np.concatenate(output_vectors)
        return self.undigitize(encoded)

    def decode(self, encoded_message):
        digits = self.digitize(encoded_message)
    
        output_vectors = []
        for i in range(len(digits) // self.vec_len):
            in_vec = digits[self.vec_len * i : self.vec_len * (i + 1)]
            shifted_vec = (in_vec - self.shift)
            multed_vec = np.matmul(self.inv, shifted_vec)
        
            out_vec = multed_vec.astype(int) % self.mod
            output_vectors.append(out_vec)
    
        decoded = np.concatenate(output_vectors)
        return self.undigitize(decoded)


alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

b = [2, 2]
A = [
    [3, 5],
    [1, 2]
]

Poly = Polyalphabetic(alphabet, 2, b, A)
print(Poly.encode(alphabet))
# Output is "HEXKNQDWTCJIZOPUFAVGLMBSRY"
print(Poly.decode(Poly.encode(alphabet)))
# Output is "ABCDEFGGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWWYZ"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a solution, though I'm still not quite sure why it was broken in the first place. I replaced the line `out_vec = multed_vec.astype(int) % self.mod` with `out_vec = np.rint(multed_vec).astype(int) % self.mod` because for some reason numpy's array.astype(int) was sometimes rounding down what should have been integers. My guess is that it was a floating point error and numpy was displaying something slightly under 15 (the P in HELP) as `15.` but when that was cast to an integer it dropped the fractional bits and got 14 (the O in HELO).

Follow up with a solution to another problem I faced. My code as it stood required that the multiplier matrix have determinant 1 or -1 in order to have an inverse with all integer entries, because getting the inverse involves dividing by the determinant. To fix this, my first approach was to multiply the inverse by the determinant of the multiplier, but then it isn't an inverse of the multiplier at all because the entries are too big. To fix that, I had to multiply it by the modular multiplicative inverse of the determinant (the number i such that det(A) * i = 1 (mod 26)). This gets the inverse back to actually being an inverse of the multiplier, but without reintroducing the fractions involved in the initial calculation of the inverse.